# Building Box2d with Cmake

Tags: cmake, box2d, glfw

I have been trying to build Box2d with Cmake on Windows. This is the first time I attempt something like this, so I followed a tutorial. However, when I clicked on 'configure' it started working until it showed me this error message:

"You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library glfw without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file".

I searched about this error on google, but I didn't find anyone with the same problem. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

**EDIT:** The versions are:

Cmake: 3.5.2
Box2d: It doesn't say. How can I tell?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to make your issue reproducible, I'd recommend you to a) provide links to the tools you use and b) provide their versions. Also, it may be a good idea to show the contents of CMakeLists.txt

Comment: If there was no error before, it's a bug in blox2d's CMake code.

Comment: What do you mean? There was an error every time I tried it.

Comment: Here I describe a minimal example of how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351640/how-to-compile-box2d-in-linux/46288300#46288300

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes up because the SOURCES haven't been set properly, Add the "else" condition as i did below will fix this.

```
if (_GLFW_COCOA)
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} cocoa_platform.h iokit_joystick.h
                 posix_tls.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} cocoa_init.m cocoa_monitor.m
                 cocoa_window.m iokit_joystick.m mach_time.c posix_tls.c)
elseif (_GLFW_WIN32)
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} win32_platform.h win32_tls.h
                 winmm_joystick.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} win32_init.c win32_monitor.c win32_time.c
                 win32_tls.c win32_window.c winmm_joystick.c)
elseif (_GLFW_X11)
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} x11_platform.h xkb_unicode.h
                 linux_joystick.h posix_time.h posix_tls.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} x11_init.c x11_monitor.c x11_window.c
                 xkb_unicode.c linux_joystick.c posix_time.c posix_tls.c)
elseif (_GLFW_WAYLAND)
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} wl_platform.h linux_joystick.h
                 posix_time.h posix_tls.h xkb_unicode.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} wl_init.c wl_monitor.c wl_window.c
                 linux_joystick.c posix_time.c posix_tls.c xkb_unicode.c)
elseif (_GLFW_MIR)
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} mir_platform.h linux_joystick.h
                 posix_time.h posix_tls.h xkb_unicode.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} mir_init.c mir_monitor.c mir_window.c
                 linux_joystick.c posix_time.c posix_tls.c xkb_unicode.c)
else()
set(glfw_HEADERS ${common_HEADERS} win32_platform.h win32_tls.h
                     winmm_joystick.h)
set(glfw_SOURCES ${common_SOURCES} win32_init.c win32_monitor.c win32_time.c
                     win32_tls.c win32_window.c winmm_joystick.c)            
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks! I pasted the block of code you gave me and configured again. The error message was gone. However, when I tried to generate the files, I got other error messages. It said: "Error in generation process, project files may be invalid".